# Mysterious subdomains to my site indexed by Google

Tags: search, google, seo, search-engines, subdomain

We have an issue with strange subdomains pointing to (pages on) our site such as:

- www2.example.com
- 2.example.com
- anothersite.com.example.com

A few things are perplexing:

- who created them? why they do that?
- why Google index them and made them appear in the search results when clicking them gets a 5xx error.
- how can we get rid of them?

It seems some type of scams that hurt our site's free search and experience.  Anyone had similar experience and knows the answers?

Comment: Try google cache to see what was on those pages. What you mean with "scams that hurt our site's free search and experience."?

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problems on some websites, if you are running apache web server you can do 301 redirect to your main domain with this code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www2|2|anothersite.com)\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you don't have dynamic subdomains, you can easily route all that backlinks to your main domain. And, this can't " hurt your site's" if you don't have content on these subdomins (you told that you have 5xx errors), if you have content on any of those subdomains, you can get problems with duplicated content, but it's usually easy to handle.
I don't know who created that subdomains, but sometimes they created accidentally, mistyping..

Comment: How exactly would those be created through mistyping? Who's mistyping? If those subdomains really do exist on a domain that the OP owns, then he needs to look into his DNS configurations, not just ignore them just because they're displaying errors rather than content.